# Revert element's background color when clicked again

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Using Angular 2, I have a table with striped rows and when I click a row it turns green and only one row can be green at a time. I want to add the functionality that if a row that is currently clicked on (turned green) is clicked again, it reverts back to the color it was before originally being clicked. Right now a row will only revert back to its original color if a different row is clicked.

Table without any rows clicked:
[image]

Table when the second row is clicked:
[image]

HTML grey is #d3d3d3. Green is #015939:

```
<tr *ngFor="let dPoint of theData; let idx=index; let even=even" (click)="onClick(dPoint, idx)" (row)="received($event)" id="{{dPoint.tDataPoint}}"
      [style.backgroundColor]="clickedRow == idx ? '#015939' : (even ? 'white' : '#d3d3d3')" [style.color]="clickedRow == idx ? 'white' : '#015939'">
    <td>{{dPoint.tDataPoint}}</td>
    <td>{{dPoint.tICCP}}</td>
    <td>{{dPoint.tStartDate}}</td>
    <td>{{dPoint.tEndDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

Typescript:

```
onClick(message:DataTable, idx:any){
  this.clickedRow = idx;
  //more code that isn't relevant to this functionality
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `idx` to a non-existing index to make no row selected:

```
onClick(message:DataTable, idx:any){
  if(this.clickedRow == idx) {
    this.clickedRow = -1;
  } else {
    this.clickedRow = idx;
  }
  //more code that isn't relevant to this functionality
}
```